# String Interpolation Not Updating in SwiftUI Environment Variable When Changed by Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui, string-interpolation

I've got a list of message examples that use string interpolation to make the example more relevant to the user. Because I've found that you cannot use variables before you initiate the class, it is created as an empty `[String]`, and then assigned a value after the `init()`. However, the variables used in the strings are then changed using a picker. Additionally, the class is used as an `@EnvironmentVariable`, and so everything is sent to a publisher when changed, which is where I think the problem lies – I think there is some problem with the interpolation that doesn't let it subscribe to the publisher changes.

The class is defined as such:

```swift
class GlobalVars: ObservableObject {

    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<GlobalVars,Never>()

    var listToChooseFrom: [String] = [
        "a list",
        "of options",
        "to be chosen from"
    ] {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    var listPos: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    var stringToChange: String {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    var output: [String] {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    init() {
        switch listPos {
        case 0:
            stringToChange = "a value"
        case 1:
            stringToChange = "another value"
        default:
            stringToChange = "toodleydoo"
        }
        output = [
            "a list",
            "with several variables",
            "defined above",
            "and one modified within the init() statement",
            "referenced within strings",
            "like \(stringToChange)."
        ]
    }
}
```

The picker is defined as such, and changes the value of `listPos` relative to `listToChooseFrom`:

```swift
Picker("Select an option", selection: $globalVars.listPos) {
    ForEach(0 ..< globalVars.listToChooseFrom) {
        Text("\(self.globalVars.listToChooseFrom[$0])")
    }
}
```

I want the code in the `init()` statement to run every time `globalVars.listPos` is changed by the picker. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Use  @Published instead of PassthroughSubject

Comment: Whats the benefit of using `@Published`? Seems to me like it does the same thing... Problem's still there.

Answer (score 2):

The real world is not like the SwiftUI world. Merely changing `this` will not also magically change `messages` just because `messages` was formed using an interpolated value of `this`. When `this` changes *you* have to set `messages` all over again.

Comment: What would be the best way to do that? get/set?

Comment: Just do again the same thing you did in `init`: set `messages`.

Comment: the value is changed in a picker... separate question/problem? Or is there some easy way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: I have no idea what or whether you are missing something. Your question is missing just about everything. No picker. If you want more help, show more code. Show enough code that we can reproduce the problem.